# Create something like a Record type for related properties

Tags: typescript

Given this example

```
class Dog {
   public key = 'dog' as const
   public speak: () => 'woof' = () => 'woof'
}

class Cat {
   public key = 'cat' as const
   public speak: () => 'meow' = () => 'meow'
}

const animals = [new Dog(), new Cat()]

type AnimalKeys = typeof animals[number]['key'] // dog | cat
type AnimalSounds = ReturnType<typeof animals[number]['speak']> // woof | meow
type GetSound = (key: AnimalKeys) => AnimalSounds

const getSound: GetSound = (key: AnimalKeys) => {
   if(key == 'dog'){
      return 'meow' // would like to see this error
   }

   return 'meow'
}
```

would it be possible to better define `GetSound` to return the *correct* AnimalSound based on the AnimalKey passed in? Currently passing in `cat` returns `'woof' | 'meow'`, ideally it would know that since `cat` is the key for `Cat`, the correct speak is `meow`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNTAHArgIxAEthoBrAUwE9oBeaAcgBMl7pJph4A7CAFw2z4iJCFnJhSALmgAKAJS0AfAwDu8eADNWdeUtXqtaAL5o0oSDADCYXqgHRcBYmSq0GwG63ace-TA6FnUXEpWQUaZXoAW3J4FW0wvWjY%20ONTHz42LkIosBAYOgBtLnIVOCR5ABpoErLrXnkAXVNeSjFoAEFs3JAAaSoC6FaxTSycvIhinCi8cgAnRsL6Ckp6RugAeg3oZmQAHw4bNGHyTu68gGV4HC5GQYAlcl4cOa4AFTbyAB4T0bBz-JTGbzRb0YISNbKLbQNSjA4xOLHT7QADiTyuN0YbhkK2kXXGfQG4WU%20J6GNuEHS3EyiHR11u0jRvHJWJ0uLOBP6lAgxLs-kIGhxrhodCYLDk6H8-jmTxeXH0mno9hM9hlz1eDARqSMQA)

Answer (score 0):

here's a way to pull out the `sound` using generics and typescripts `Extract<>` utility

```
type Animal = typeof animals[number]
type Key = Animal['key'] // 'dog' | 'cat'
type Sounds<T extends Key> = Extract<Animal, { key: T }>['speak']
type Returns<T extends Key> = ReturnType<Sounds<T>>

type DogSound = Returns<'dog'> // woof
type CatSound = Returns<'cat'> // meow
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNTAHArgIxAEthoBrAUwE9oBeaAcgBMl7pJph4A7CAFw2z4iJCFnJhSALmgAKAJS0AfAwDu8eADNWdeUtXqtaAL5o0oSDADCYXqgHRcBYmSq0GwG63ace-TA6FnUXEpWQUaZXoAW3J4FW0wvWjY%20ONTHz42LkIosBAYOgBtLnIVOCR5ABpoErLrXnkAXVNeSjFoAEFs3JA3VrFNLJy8iGKcKLxyACdm-vJoAGlXOi7hkEL6Ckp6RugAej2GZkRWAB93TzQ56ABleBwuRggAHgAVaHIAD15yR5glyjKOgAUW%20UzAwF4z1WPWqKBclGk7yMig2wQkOyubXmACVyLwcFMeG8Pt9fk9FlQgdA8QSia9sc87g8nm9FIoWtjyohmY83LTCcSmCxlAdoGpNFj2vVeYx%20fjBS96B5ePRRYcYnEgA)